# Confused about maximum a posteriori estimation

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, map-estimation

I am new to Bayesian statistics, and I just came across MAP. [image: MAP definition from wiki]

When our prior is a continuous distribution (pdf) on $\theta$ how can we calculate $g(\theta)$ in the numerator?

**Edit:**

I assumed $g(\theta)$ is probability but found that $g(\theta)$ in the numerator is actually density.

Comment: I've edited your question to use math typesetting. More information https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). Please use the math typsetting CV offers when you do so. & please add relevant clarifications into the body of your question, not buried elsewhere in comments.

Answer (score 1):

$g(\theta)$ is the prior distribution over the parameter space $\Theta$.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. However, I am wondering how can we calculate the probability of a particular value from a continuous distribution. If it is PMF, we can get p(theta) for a particular value of theta. Please advise if I am thinking wrong.

Comment: @ajitsamudrala I think this is a good clarification to edit into your question.

Comment: The equation you posted only requires us to evaluate probability *densities* at particular values of $\theta$.